# Correspondence between submodules and quotient modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

What is the (natural) bijection between the isomorphic class of sub modules and isomorphic class of quotient modules of a finitely generated torsion module over a PID.
Is there any inclusion relation between these classes?

Comment: $(N \subset M) \leftrightarrow (M / N)$

Comment: My intuitive guess is also this same correspondence. but I could not prove that non isomorphic sub modules have non isomorphic quotient modules.. is this very obvious? thanks.   

Comment: It's not true in general that non-isomorphic submodules give non-isomorphic quotients.  For example, in the abelian group (i.e., $\mathbb Z$-module) $(\mathbb Z/4)\times(\mathbb Z/2)$, the cyclic subgroup $(\mathbb Z/4)\times0$ and the non-cyclic subgroup $(2\mathbb Z/4)\times(\mathbb Z/2)$ both produce quotients that are cyclic of order 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M=R/(p^n)$ with $p$ prime, the result is clear.  Since an arbitrary $M$ is a direct sum of such modules, the result is still clear.

Comment: I try to prove the arbitrary case, for a particular sub module I could not identify the corresponding quotient module. can you explain me.